# we know that composition two uniformly continous function is uniformly continous.Is the converse true?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Question: we know that composition two uniformly continous function is uniformly continous.Is the converse true?
Thought: Since $f(x)= \sin^2(x)$ is uniformly continuous, but $x^2$ is not, the converse is not true. But I am thinking that is there any general setting to that, I mean if $f(g(x))$ is uniformly continuous then can we put some restriction on $f$ or $g$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If either $f$ or $g$ is constant then $f(g(x))$ is also, so is as uniformly continuous as a function can get.  The non-constant one can be as wild as you want.

Comment: That's not particularly interesting, though.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122:  it shows you cannot put any restriction on $f$ or $g$ without further information.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 When presenting counterexamples, I generally  prefer simple ones rather than interesting ones. The objective is to show that the claim is false, not to entertain people. In some cases, a really simple counterexample clearly exhibits a defect in the question and thus leads to an improvement of the question. More complicated examples are less likely to have that effect.